# Torque PBS Some bash shell commands work, Some do not

Tags: bash, shell, pbs, torque

When this simple torque pbs bash script is submitted...

```
#PBS -N test 

which hostname      #get file spec for hostname command
which ifconfig      #get file spec for ifconfig command

/usr/bin/hostname   #get the hostname
/usr/sbin/ifconfig  #list network interfaces

date                #report the date/time
printenv | grep PBS #get PBS environment variables

echo End of Job     #a convenient marker
```

....successfully reports the output of the
"which" commands...

```
/bin/hostname
/usr/sbin/ifconfig
```

...but when the script invokes /bin/hostname and /usr/sbin/ifconfig,
there is no error reported, and there is no output. There is nothing.
The script goes on to successfully report the results of the date
command...

```
Wed Feb  4 12:10:44 EST 2015
```

...and the results of the printenv and echo commands...

```
PBS_VERSION=TORQUE-3.0.4
PBS_JOBNAME=pbs.test.sh.c
PBS_ENVIRONMENT=PBS_BATCH
PBS_O_WORKDIR=/home/ccluster/gpp/pbs.test
PBS_TASKNUM=1
PBS_O_HOME=/home/ccluster/gpp
PBS_MOMPORT=15003
PBS_GPUFILE=/var/lib/torque/aux//1483.c4.cs.unh.edugpu
PBS_O_QUEUE=c00q1
.
.
.
End of Job
```

What would explain that some shell commands work and some do not?

Comment: You might have error messages in a separate file

Comment: Are those stub commands?  Do they do anything if you invoke them interactively, as the same user/group as what PBS runs them as?

Comment: Note that /bin/hostname is equivalent to /usr/bin/hostname in the above

Comment: "You might have error messages in a separate file"...yes there is a separate error file which contains the output of the bash "-v" flag, but there are no errors associated with the hostname and ifconfig commands. Also, these commands run successfully interactively under the same user as what PBS uses.

Comment: I also find that `#PBS -N test` in the script and `PBS_JOBNAME=pbs.test.sh.c`in the output do not match. That is you could be submitting a different script.

Comment: The "#PBS -N test" in the script gives a name for the job in the queue and provides a file name for the error and output files. This is a convenience when looking at a long queue of jobs and for customizing the names of error and output files when making repeated runs. The PBS_JOBNAME environment variable is the name of the script submitted as a job, pbs.test.sh.c in this case.

Comment: Another interesting twist on this problem is issuing the hostname command under control of the strace utitlity. So the relevant line in the script becomes "/usr/bin/strace /usr/bin/hostname". The key line in the output from strace is "write (1, "c00.cs.unh.edu\n", 15)   = 15"  "c00.cs.unh.edu" is the correct hostname, but that write operation does not send its output to the PBS output file for the job.